Avoiding time zone translation for serialized strings containing dates when using Cosmos DB trigger
We're converting our Cosmos DB triggered Azure function from in-process model to isolated.
Since we want to retain ability to use fluent JSON schema, we're not using a POCO class for trigger inputs and use JObject instead.
Here's our trigger:
            [CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "%SourceCosmosDatabaseName%",
            containerName: OurContainerName,
            Connection = "CosmosConnectionString",
            LeaseDatabaseName = "%CosmosDatabaseName%",
            LeaseContainerName = LeaseContainerName,
            LeaseContainerPrefix = LeaseContainerNewStatusPrefix,
            CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true,
            StartFromBeginning = true)]
            IReadOnlyList<JObject> inputs,
            FunctionContext functionContext)

The problem is that strings containing date times are automatically parsed and converted to DateTime by Azure functions, which converts them to the server's time zone, i.e. string "2023-05-15T20:05:00-05:00" becomes "2023-05-16T04:05:00+03:00"
I tried giving the DateParseHandling.None option in JSON serialization settings as it is described in documentation, but they don't seem to be respected:
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
            {
                builder.Services.Configure<WorkerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    var settings = NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer.CreateJsonSerializerSettings();
                    settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
                    options.Serializer = new NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer(settings);
                });
            })


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Set the type of your resulting DateTime Properties on the target object to DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime. It will then preserve the offset
